# How can I define a runner dynamically using vars context?

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to create dynamic workflows in GitHub Actions to lock down environments. I created a new environment called TEST and created several variables, one of which I called `RUNNER`. The value of the `RUNNER` variable is simply self-hosted.

If I run this:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  greeting_job:
    environment: TEST  
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: "Greeting with Environment Variables"
        run: echo "${{ vars.GREETING }} ${{ vars.FIRST_NAME }}. Today is ${{ vars.DAY_OF_WEEK }}! Runner - ${{ vars.RUNNER }}"
```

I am able to `echo` all the variables, including `RUNNER`, and the workflow runs successfully.

When I replace `self-hosted` with the `RUNNER` and run it:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  greeting_job:
    environment: TEST  
    runs-on: ${{ vars.RUNNER }}
    steps:
      - name: "Greeting with Environment Variables"
        run: echo "${{ vars.GREETING }} ${{ vars.FIRST_NAME }}. Today is ${{ vars.DAY_OF_WEEK }}! Runner - ${{ vars.RUNNER }}"
```

I get this error:

```
 Error when evaluating 'runs-on' for job 'greeting_job'. .github/workflows/TEST.yml (Line: 12, Col: 14): Unexpected value ''
```

I'm expecting the `RUNNER` variable value `self-hosted` to be used in the `runs-on` part of the workflow.

Based on the GitHub variable [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables), this is exactly how it should be formatted, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Apparently, looks like a bug. Tested with this [workflow](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxljrEOwjAMRHd/hQekTuUDMsPaoYI5CsFVA8Su4jQdqv47ShhZbrjTezp2kQwqZZtWVitspyTRFpcUQNjgJuk9fWSzz6CLy34GeMlDDSD6UBORuIQkHImzwQuVVlZdXwWnfceqO4/3YbiOeBxt10yL/vgeub24keZWNNog+Vmw++c7+AKkQTkt) and failed with the same error i.e. "**Error when evaluating 'runs-on' for job 'ci'. .github/workflows/ci-set-runs-on-from-vars.yml (Line: 8, Col: 14): Unexpected value ''**".

Comment: Thanks for taking a gander @Azeem, logged a bug report with GitHub.

Comment: Sure thing. Please share the issue link here for reference. Thanks!

Comment: Link with GitHub support: https://support.github.com/ticket/personal/0/2121299

Comment: Hi @donahj07, I can't access the ticket. Is it still open? Running into a similar problem but will try the solution mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works while using `vars` directly as documented in the [example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values) does not, as OP discovered.

1. In your workflow, create a prerequisite job that takes a workflow input but on a hosted runner and sets the runner name as its output.
2. Use the output from the prerequisite job to set the runner name on subsequent jobs.

The final workflow will look something like this:

```
name: Example Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      runner:
        required: false
        description: 'Runner name'
        default: 'dev-runner'

jobs:
  prereq:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Provision step # at least one step is required in a job
        run: |
          echo "Provisioning ${{ github.event.inputs.runner }}"
    outputs:
      runner: ${{ github.event.inputs.runner }}
  actualjob:
    needs: prereq
    runs-on: ${{ needs.prereq.outputs.runner }}
    steps:
      - name: Ta-da
        run: echo "success!"
```